# Is it possible to turn the inputValue in my Apps Script below into hard coded text so that the note only display text?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a set of data with contact information that I have used concatenate in order to combine into one column. I wish to add a note with the same information to each cell so that the contact information is visible when mousing over so that I don't have to increase the size of the cell for the information to be visible.

I've played around a little bit with google apps script and managed to create a note based on the correct cell but the problem is that the note only shows me the concatenate formula and not the contact information. Is there a way to change the format in the script so that the note displays the contact information instead of the formula? or is there some simple workaround that can be used?

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var spreadSheet = e.source;
  var inputValue = e.value;
  var SheetName = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getName();

  if(SheetName == 'Apps Script' && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.rowStart != 1)
    e.range.offset(0,1).setNote([inputValue]).setValue([inputValue]);
}
```

Best Regards
Joakim

Comment: setNote() requires a string.  setValues() requires a two dimensional array.  try just e.value

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the value of the cell, not the value that was inputted. You can do that by adding this line:

`var rawText = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnStart).getValue();`

And changing the Note value to `rawText`. Below is the full code with these changes implemented.

```js
function onEdit(e) {

  var spreadSheet = e.source;
  var inputValue = e.value;

  var rawText = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnStart).getValue();
  //console.log(rawText);
  
  var SheetName = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getName();

  if(SheetName == 'Apps Script' && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.rowStart != 1)
    e.range.offset(0,1).setNote(rawText).setValue([inputValue]);
}
```

---

Updated Code:

```js
function onEdit(e) {

  var spreadSheet = e.source;
  var inputValue = e.value;
  var rawText = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnStart).getValue();
  //console.log(rawText);
  var SheetName = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getName();

  if(SheetName == 'Case1' && e.range.columnStart == 3 && e.range.rowStart != 1)
    var noteText = e.range.offset(0,34).getValue();
    e.range.offset(0,1).setNote(noteText).setValue(noteText);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks alot for the help. Now it shows the correct information in the right place. However it seems like it does not update when I update contact information. Is it possible to make the script react to not only changes I make to the cell but to changes that occur due to changes i make in other Cells?

Comment: I have all the contact information on a separate sheet so it would be ideal if the script ran whenever i made any change to the sheet called "Contact information".

Comment: @joakimgranat is the cell you want to update with the note also on the Contact Information sheet? Or is it something where you edit a value on that sheet, and it changes the value in Column A (which would then need to be added to a note in Col B like above)? Would you be able to share an example sheet of what you're trying to do?

Comment: The document looks roughtly like this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o1P7h6owumalsEhlynh79Aj58xclN7z87cLnbckWhds/edit?usp=sharing

So I Edit information (A couple of hundre rows) in column C-M on the sheet named "Contact information". The information is summed up as I like it to be shown by a simple concatentate formula in column N.  In the sheet "Case" I then use a Vlookup in column AK to map the info from the contact sheet with the right customer. The Script you helped me with offsets the info from column AK to column D as text and in a Note on the sheet case.

Comment: Sorry, new to this forum. I seem to have forgotten to mention you in the post.

Comment: I've modified the formula slightly to fit the actual sheet as below: `function onEdit(e) { var spreadSheet = e.source; var inputValue = e.value; var rawText = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnStart).getValue(); //console.log(rawText); var SheetName = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getName(); if(SheetName == 'Case' && e.range.columnStart == 37 && e.range.rowStart != 2) e.range.offset(0,-33).setNote(rawText).setValue(rawText); }`

Comment: @joakimgranat okay, i think i understand what you're trying to do. It seems that in the Case sheet, the ID numbers don't automatically fill in, meaning the values from Contact Information cannot be brought over automatically. With this, we can assume that the last thing you would do is paste in the ID into column C on the Case sheet. Using this information, I have altered the code above and edited my answer. The only catch is that you need to make sure you paste the ID in column C last. Is this more along the lines of what you were looking for?